# Transpose 4x4 int32 matrix using NEON

Tags: assembly, arm, intrinsics, neon

How can I efficiently transpose a matrix represented as four `int32x4t` values? I cannot use `ld4q_s32` and `st4q_s32`.

Comment: Actual 32-bit mode NEON, where you can access 64-bit `d0-31` halves of 128-bit `q0-15` registers for nearly free?  (At least in asm; compilers often do a bad job with partial registers).  Any particular microarchitecture you're interested in, like only 64-bit M1, or will this run on in-order pipelines like cortex-A53 or A72 where `tbl` is slowish?  (https://www.cnx-software.com/2017/08/07/how-arm-nerfed-neon-permute-instructions-in-armv8/)

Comment: Why can't you use these instructions?  Are there any other instructions you can't use?

Comment: @fuz: I was assuming it was because the data was already in registers as the result of a computation, so store / reload wouldn't be efficient.  But yeah, it'd be good if the question clarified the reason.  (Along with what microarchitectures are relevant.)

Comment: Data is already in registers so I cannot use those. Architecture is Cortex A53.

Comment: You'll want the [transpose instructions](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102159/0400/Permutation---Neon-instructions?lang=en#md492-permutation---neon-instructions__transpose-instructions). [Intrinsics version](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#q=trn), especially [this one](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vtrn1q_s32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transposing is typically implemented in the recursive form:

```
   [A B]' == [A' C']
   [C D]     [B' D']
```

where each `A,B,C,D` can be though of being a square matrix (and A' == A, for 1x1 matrices).

Using transpose will unfortunately help you only on the level that needs to transpose the lowest 2x2 matrices in parallel -- the ARM64 instruction set lacks an instruction to transpose the highest level, i.e. 64 bits at a time, which was done on arm-v7 as `swp d2, d0`.

There's anyway another iterative formula for transpose: it's repeatedly unzipping or zipping the input.

in *octave/matlab language* we define the zip operator as one, that takes the first N/2 elements of an array `a` and interleaves them with the last N/2 elements of an array.

```
  zip = @(a) [a(1:end/2);a(end/2+1:end)](:)';
  zip(0:15) %--> 0  8  1  9  2 10  3 11  4 12  5 13  6 14  7 15
  zip(ans)  %--> 0  4  8 12  1  5  9 13  2  6 10 14  3  7 11 15
```

Thus the complete code using intrinsics could be something like:

```
inline int32x4x4_t zip(int32x4x4_t a) {
   return { vzip1q_s32(a.val[0], a.val[2]),
            vzip2q_s32(a.val[0], a.val[2]),
            vzip1q_s32(a.val[1], a.val[3]),
            vzip2q_s32(a.val[1], a.val[3]) };
}

int32x4x4_t transpose(int32x4x4_t a) {
    return zip(zip(a));
}
```

On some architectures one can also utilise `vtbl`, if one has 8 extra registers to spare (4 for the indices and 4 for the output)

```
uint8x16x4_t transpose_vtbl(uint8x16x4_t a) {
   return {
      vqtbl4q_u8(a, idx0),
      vqtbl4q_u8(a, idx1),
      vqtbl4q_u8(a, idx2),
      vqtbl4q_u8(a, idx3)};
}
```

Here the `int32x4x4_t input` needs to be cast element-wise with `vreinterpretq_u8_s32(input.val[i])` and back, with `idx0` having the values of `0 1 2 3 16 17 18 19 32 33 34 35 48 49 50 51`, `idx1 == idx0 + 4` and so on.

On M1 or M2 VTBL seems to instruction level parallelise, contrary to eg. a moderately recent cortex A75 (v8.2), where the vtbl takes 3N+1 clock cycles with no dual-issue capabilities.